# Snapshot in firebase. how to dig deeper into the snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, snapshot

currently my data is as such

```
{
    'listone':
        {
        'entrydate1':
            {
            'random key 1':
                {
                'name': 'Chris';
                'date': '24 May 2016'
                }
            'random key 2':
                {
                'name': 'John';
                'date': '25 May 2016'
                }
            }
        'entrydate2':
            {
            'random key 1':
                {
                'name': 'Chris';
                'date': '24 May 2016'
                }
            'random key 2':
                {
                'name': 'John';
                'date': '25 May 2016'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The random key is generated by firebase `childByAutoID()`

The question is when I get my snapshot, how do I get the details of each random key? Basically I need to retrieve the data from `listone` and I will populate my `tableview` by sorting the earliest `entrydate`. however after getting the snapshot I am lost as to how I can get the information out of the snapshot.

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid

    let listOneRef = ref.child(uid + "/listone")

    _ = listOneRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in


        for item in snapshot.children {
            let child = item.children.allObjects

            for snap in child {
                //anyitems was initialized as [AnyObject] array
                self.anyitems.append(snap)

            }
        }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

I have no idea how to actually make use of the details. when I print `anyitems` I do see some details i.e.

```
[Snap (-KJ-jqTNf3MTtY8YRH-3) {
Name = "Chris";
Date = "30 May 2016";
}, Snap (-KJ01QYoTedZkClsf13Y) {
Name = "John";
Date = "30 May 2016";
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on Xcode right now so I can't verify, but it should be something like:

```
for snapshot in anyitems {
    print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Name"))
}
```

And I think subscripting should also work:

```
for snapshot in anyitems {
    print(snapshot.value["Name"])
}
```

---

If you need to tell the type to the compiler:

```
for snapshot in anyitems as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("Name"))
}
```

But it would be better, as you've noticed, to safely cast the array before accessing its content:

```
if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. however, anyitems is `AnyObject`. so there would not be `snapshot.value`

Comment: That's why I made the third example. :)

Comment: oh right! I tried that and it didnt work but I declared it as FIRDataSnapshot when I let ... = ... and it worked. basically from the start I would declare as such `if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]` and continue my loop down and I will get the correct outputs thanks!

Comment: perhaps you can edit your answer and I can mark it correct

Comment: I've fixed my faulty "snap" to "FIRDataSnapshot" in my answer, thanks! I knew I'd make a mistake by not checking in Xcode. :p